# Google Sheets with JDBC - IP range

Tags: sql-server, google-apps-script, google-sheets, ip, firewall

my first post here.

I have been trying to make Google Sheets talk to one of our internal databases and I came across this website: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc

It has all the IPs that need to be whitelisted in the firewall so that the sheet can talk to our database. However, I was very concerned about granting such access to a tremendously large amount of IPs to one of our internal servers, especially not having clear if these IPs belong only to the Google Sheets (or Google Drive, for that matter) service or if it overlaps with another Google service, such as Google Cloud.

The Google IP range is as follows:
64.18.0.0 - 64.18.15.255
64.233.160.0 - 64.233.191.255
66.102.0.0 - 66.102.15.255
66.249.80.0 - 66.249.95.255
72.14.192.0 - 72.14.255.255
74.125.0.0 - 74.125.255.255
173.194.0.0 - 173.194.255.255
207.126.144.0 - 207.126.159.255
209.85.128.0 - 209.85.255.255
216.239.32.0 - 216.239.63.255

Does anyone know if these IPs belong to Google Sheets/Drive only or if it overlaps with another Google service?

Please let me know if you have any questions or concerns.

Comment: I think it overlaps all of Google services. Just do a [tag:whois] lookup.

Comment: I found a link to google ip ranges on this page https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc : https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/goog.txt